# android app displaying different content than ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

So I am developing an app and I am not sure what had happened. I have everything set up correctly on the ADT but the emulator and my device show up differently. I'm not sure what code to put up. I have tabs with scrollview and text on the ADT but my device just has no tabs and the text overlaying eachother

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would personally try would be to uninstall the application from the mobile device and rerun the code. Second thing to check would be the resolution off both devices? Maybe your mobile has lower resolution than the emulator and as a result the displayed output  is a mess? Are you getting the expected output displayed in the emulator? I am nowhere near good at android development, but that's what I would try. Hope I helped at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks but I had tried that but it didn't work. The emulator is displaying the same content as my device and the ADT is displaying that it works with all resolutions. This is my first "bug" I have come across.